# ui-sref gets instantiated before ajax call that populates it's links

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router, angular-services, ui-sref

I have a controller which gets data through a service and than populate a template with returned values. I use `ui-router` with states. This template contains `ui-sref` directives that also need to be populated **after the ajax call**. Service use a path from where to  load data which is given by the controller.

The problem is that those directive are loaded to be instantiated before my controller gets any data - so I get errors.

If I put those values in controller directly works fine but I have a service that set that values which are read from a file.

Is there a way to make those directive wait until my controller have al data loaded?

Comment: My only workaround was to use directly href and populate it with a formatted link with #/ in front

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('example', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-click=\"clickMe()\">Click me</button>',

        link: function(scope) {
            scope.clickMe = function() {
                scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Yeahh.. the thing is that the service need a path from where to load data and that path is given from controller

Comment: the other solution is ng-hide use this property to hide that part and make it visible once your service has finished all of it's task because you can't stop  it from loading .

Comment: I did it like this: `<a ng-show="items.available" ui-sref="{{props.rightLink}}">`.

 And in controller ` $scope.items = {available: false}; getData().then(){$scope.items = {available: true}; } ` - not the whole code but like this

Comment: I've modified it like this `module.directive('customFooter', function(){
  return {
   retrict: 'E', // E vine d ela element
   templateUrl: '_global/views/templates/custom-footer.html',
   link: function (scope) {    
     scope.showMe = scope.items.available;
   }
  };
 });` but it doesn't update when items.available = true

Comment: use $scope.items.available = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120244/discussion-between-stx-and-vikash).

Comment: still, link from directive fires before data is fetched in controller so items.active is false